# removeFromParent() automatically called when an SKSpriteNode moves off the SKScene

Tags: sprite-kit

It is my understanding that SKSpriteNodes that have been added to the SKScene will linger there until removeFromParent(), or any of the other remove methods are called.

I haven't touched SpriteKit for 2 months, and that's what I remember it to be. But for some reason, today when I was programming, I realized something odd; I was looking at my node count and it was not being increased even though I am doing a `.repeatActionForever` that keeps instantiating a new SKSpriteNode that runs across the screen. There are no `remove` calls anywhere in the code. Here's the block of code that creates the SKSpriteNode:

```
//function in GameScene
func spawnEnemy() {
    let enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemy")
    enemy.position = CGPoint(x: size.width + enemy.size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
    let actionMove = SKAction.moveToX(-enemy.size.width/2, duration: 2.0)
    enemy.runAction(actionMove)
}

//inside update()
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.runBlock(spawnEnemy))
```

Here's a gif of what the simulator showed: http://i.imgur.com/c8eyFDE.gif

I was under the impression that the stampede of old lady in dresses would linger off the screen and the node count for continue to build up, but for some reason, the node count stays constant at 42 nodes, as if the nodes that are off screen are automatically removed.

Again, I have no remove calls anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node count only counts the nodes visible on screen. Therefore you've got a constant 42 nodes on screen and many more off screen.

To check nothing is being removed though, you could subclass `SKSpriteNode` like so:

```
class Enemy : SKSpriteNode {
    override func removeFromParent() {
        super.removeFromParent()
        println("An enemy was removed!")
    }
}
```

Then in your scene:

```
let enemy = Enemy(imageNamed: "enemy")
```

Now, if an enemy is somehow being removed you'll definitely know.

If it turns out the enemies are persisting after they've moved off the screen I would recommend using either of the following to remove the nodes:

**1.** Use `runAction(_ action: SKAction!, completion block: (() -> Void)!)` like so:

```
enemy.runAction(actionMove) { enemy.removeFromParent() }
```

**2.** Use `SKAction.removeFromParent()` and create a sequence of `SKActions`:

```
let actionMove = SKAction.moveToX(-enemy.size.width/2, duration: 2.0)
let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()

enemy.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, remove]))
```

Hope that helps answer you question.

Comment: So the showsNodeCount doesn't apply to nodes that go off screen? Weird...

By the way, I created all those cat ladies and even after a while, the game didn't lag. I was expecting that if I don't remove them, eventually my game will start lagging due to the amount of objects instantiated.

Comment: I would have thought that too, but SpriteKit is pretty well optimised to run with a lot of nodes at once. I suspect if you left it for long enough it would start slowing down. Did you check you weren't removing them anywhere else?

Comment: No removal calls anywhere else. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

There may be some bugs in your code:

1.I hadn't see any code about adding a node in the scene. Enemies need to be added to the scene or child of the scene.
2.The method repeadActionForever doesn't need to be called for more than one times. It will run the block inside automatically.

Try to fix them and let me know what happens.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out to me, I forgot to write `addChild(enemy)` as part of the question, but it does exist in my code.